# « Et pour ce la nommames l'Isle ès Coudres » : sens et choix de préposition ?

Tags: prépositions, articles, histoire, contractions, toponymes

*Jacques Cartier*, le 6 septembre 1535, lors de son [deuxième voyage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Cartier#Le_deuxi.C3.A8me_voyage_.281535-1536.29), traite ainsi de ce qu'il voit :

[image]
<sup>[ Extraits de deux éditions ([Gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k84126j/f39.image), [Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=w7UTAAAAYAAJ&dq=cartier%20voyage%20couldres&pg=PA135#v=onepage&q=cartier%20voyage%20couldres&f=false)) des *Voyages de découverte au Canada, entre les années 1534 et 1542*, de Jacques Cartier ; voir surtout le manuscrit 5653 de la [*Seconde navigation*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k109478b/f1.image), de la main de Cartier ; aussi [documentaire](https://www.onf.ca/film/pour_la_suite_du_monde/). ]</sup>

---

Il s'agit d'une description de l'[*Île **aux** Coudres*](http://www.toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/toposweb/Fiche.aspx?no_seq=15427) sur le fleuve Saint-Laurent. Le [*coudre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coudre/1) est un noisetier. On fait usage de la préposition archaïque [*ès*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A8s), aujourd'hui réservée à des trucs figés et aux noms de lieux (on donne souvent en toponymie l'exemple *Riom-ès-Montagnes*), par contraction de la préposition avec l'article défini au pluriel dans *en les*.<sup>1</sup> C'est presque [exclusivement](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4406) employé avec un nom au pluriel. Au *LBU14* on en discute (§580), et dans une note (H5) on signale que « [*a*]*u* et parfois *aux* ont absorbé les formes contractées avec en » mais pourtant on dit plus loin que généralement *ès* est assimilé à une préposition avec pour valeur essentiellement *en*. De plus, dans les dictionnaires, on ne mentionne pas ([*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A8s/30910/difficulte), [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A8s#frm)) la préposition *à* avec l'article (*au/aux*) et on réfère toujours uniquement à *en/dans/en matière de*.

- Que voulait-on dire exactement avec ce *ès* dans *Île ès Coudres* ; est-ce un emploi particulier par métonymie qui diffère des autres emplois de *ès* dans le texte ; au final *Île ès Coudres* et *Île aux Coudres* sont-ils équivalents ?
- Si on modernise des noms (de lieux) en France et ailleurs, qui contenaient *ès* (nom *ès* nom), est-ce avec la préposition *à* (*au/aux*), avec *en (les)/dans (les)*, ou avec *les* seul ; pourquoi ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *[Ens](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/144296) ès* ; voir aussi *ille*, en article, au [*FEW*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/141899) ; on peut aussi explorer dans l'[*ALF*](http://cartodialect.imag.fr/cartoDialect/carteTheme) la prononciation de l'article ([les arbres](http://cartodialect.imag.fr/cartoDialect/seadragon.jsp?carte=CarteALF0052), [aux autres](http://cartodialect.imag.fr/cartoDialect/seadragon.jsp?carte=CarteALF0076), [aux quilles](http://cartodialect.imag.fr/cartoDialect/seadragon.jsp?carte=CarteALF1122)) etc. dans les dialectes du français.</sub>

Comment: Avais-tu lu [ceci](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/es.html),  parce qu'il me semble que ça répond à ta/tes question(s), et plus. Je n'ai pas le temps d'en faire une réponse pour l'instant.

Comment: @Laure Merci, non je n'avais pas lu, là oui. Mais c'est qu'on peut aisément concevoir un nom de lieu dans les montagnes, mais un lieu dans un noisetier, à un noisetier, alors que l'Île est située dans l'eau sur le Fleuve. Pourquoi Cartier n'a-t-il pas utilisé _des_, par exemple ? J'ai même pensé un moment que son emploi de ès dans _Isle ès Couldres_ c'était humoristique (submergé par); me suis demandé si même il avait pu dire _aux_ mais écrire _ès_ ; si on ne voulait pas écrire la préposition _à_ pour la même raison que la vision étendue/ponctuelle avec noms de pays i.e. à pas utilisé quand la

Comment: destination est atteinte (ad pour accusatif de direction vs. a ablatif de situation). Aussi j'ai remarqué des noms du genre (je brode un nom) _St-Pierre-les-Liens_. J'infère que certains de ces noms comportaient ès auparavant, et si c'était exact je me demande pourquoi on n'a pas _aux_ dans ces cas, etc. Mutatis mutandis avec _en/en les_. Une réponse serait la bienvenue ! Merci.

Answer (score 3):

Je n'ai pas en tête d'exemple de modernisation de noms de lieux comportant la préposition *ès*, en revanche il semble qu'elle signifie plus souvent *en*, *dans* ou *au milieu de* que *aux*. Je pense aux noms de Val-ès-Dunes en Normandie ou de Pierrefitte-ès-bois dans le Loiret par exemple.

Concernant l'Île-aux-coudres, le texte de Jacques Cartier que vous citez sert d'introduction à un beau film que Pierre Perrault et Michel Brault y tournèrent dans les années 1960: *Pour la suite du monde*. L'île est alors entourée de troncs d'arbres, plantés dans l'eau pour servir de piège dans la chasse aux marsouins. Cette technique n'existait probablement pas lorsque Cartier arriva sur les lieux, mais donne *a posteriori* une autre dimension au *ès* qui vous pose problème!

Comment: ouille! Il était tard, j'ai mélangé les Perrault et oublié Michel Brault! Désolée, je corrige!

Comment: Merci ! Je connais bien ce documentaire de Brault, qui m'inspire en partie la question. Bienvenue en passant. Notez que ce n'est pas l'Île qui est entourée mais bien une zone à la pointe sud-ouest de ladite Île, un enclos pour ainsi dire, constitué de 3500 _harts_ ou petits troncs d'arbres enfoncés dans le fond du fleuve et disposés en forme de "C" de sorte qu'à marée basse le marsouin s'y prenait en contexte de pêche commerciale avant 1924. La « trace » de la pêche ce sont ces chicots ou ce qui reste des perches plantées lors des pêches précédentes. Mais ce _ès_ m'intrigue toujours !

Answer (score 1):

Je ne résouds rien ici, mais voici quelques réflexions à la lumière des documents présentés, certaines réflexions ne faisant d’ailleurs que reproduire d’autres déjà émises ici.

---

[L’article lié par Laure en commentaire à la question](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/es.html) ainsi que le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A8s) mentionnent la prononciation [ε] pour *ès*. L’absorbption par *au/aux* de certaines utilisations anciennes de *ès* semble reférer principalement à des noms de lieux, où l’occupation continuelle du lieu a sûrement plus facilement maintenu l’absence du son *« S »* dans le nom, ne modifiant que la valeur de la voyelle dans certains cas, et peut-être l’orthographe du lieu dans le cas de l’île aux Coudres. La résurrection du mot dans les expressions comme *ès lettres* est un phénomène différent, érudit et très occasionnel, non local et quotidien, auquel l’usage a ajouté la prononciation du *« S »*. On a alors collé de près à une définition précise et historique (contraction de « en les »), et il n’y avait aucune raison de créer un lien avec « au/aux ».

Si l’on examine d’autres lieux mentionnés, on rencontre par exemple *ès-Montagnes, ès-Bois* ou *ès-Dunes,* et l’on peut percevoir que ces endroits sont inclus dans lesdites montagnes, forêts, dunes, etc. L’OP mentionne pertinemment que ce genre de dénomination, utilisant des phénomènes de géographie terrestres entourant entièrement un lieu, s’applique moins bien à une île, qu’on s’attendrait davantage à voir nommée *ès-Eaux* ou *ès-Rapides* (pour l’*île ès Couldres* dont il est ici question), ou bien *ès-Marais* ou *ès-Joncs* (pour d’autres îles hypothétiques). Pourquoi donc nommer une île comme étant contenue par son contenu? Une hypothèse qui vient immédiatement à l’esprit serait de penser que les coudres poussaient le long du rivage et que leurs branches surplombent même le fleuve environnant, empêchant l’accès facile à l’île, voire à un simple point d’amarrage. Mais la plume de Jacques Cartier est parfaitement claire sur ce point : l’île a été nommée ainsi à cause de la profusion de coudres sur l’île.

Je vois deux scénarios possibles :

- S’il s’agit d’une première observation dans le Nouveau Monde de cette essence, il demeure possible qu’une densité moyenne de ceux-ci ait été suffisante à justifier l’appelation, incertains qu’ils étaient de ce que de futures explorations leur révéleraient. Peut-être alors que ces coudres sont les plus grands arbres de l’île, que ce sont eux qui en forment l’aspect et la physionomie, la distinguant clairement des autres îles. Le plancher de l’île lui-même pourrait ne s’apercevoir que de très près, ce qui justifierait l’idée d’inclusion de l’île dans les coudres via le nom *« île ès Couldres »*.
- Si par contre il s’agissait d’une densité vraiment extraordinaire, si le sol d’une section de l’île *(n’oublions pas que Jacques Cartier mentionne «  de beaulx et grandz arbres de plusieurs sortes »)* était tout simplement jonché des fruits des années précédentes, et recouvert des troncs et systèmes de racines des coudres, sans oublier les branches cassées, au point que cette section de l’île était littéralement « cachée » sous les coudres, on pourrait facilement comprendre pourquoi l’appelation *« île ès Couldres »* semble avoir convenu. Un exemple très proche, complètement anachronique mais néanmoins parlant — *et même imagé pour notre plus grand plaisir par Antoine de Saint-Exupéry* — de ce genre d’envahissement serait l’astéroïde négligé par son habitant dans *Le petit prince*, que l’on pourrait très correctement nommer *l’astéroïde ès Baobabs*. Il y aurait alors sans doute un peu d’humour dans le nom choisi, hypothèse déjà émise par l’OP, et plausible aussi selon moi.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

« Pourquoi Cartier n'a-t-il pas utilisé *des*, par exemple ?»  Parce qu'il n'écrivait pas au XXIe siècle :-) Ça fait longtemps aussi qu'on ne dit plus « pour ce. »  Rien de bizarre à ça.

Comment: Merci, _des_ est-il inconnu à l'époque de Cartier ; est-il uniquement employé au 21e ?

Comment: Absolument pas inconnu.  Mais l'usage etait different.  Considerez aussi que Cartier n'etait que legerement francais, en fait il etait Breton, quand c'etait encore un pays independant.  Le francais n'etait donc pas sa langue maternelle.  De couper les cheveux en quatre sur sa terminology ne vous apprendra strictement rien..