# Usage du néologisme/anglicisme "linker"

Tags: anglicismes

De l'anglais *link*, qui désigne un lien (quasi toujours un lien hypertexte), puis *to link*, qui signifie lier, ou ici "donner un lien", je me retrouve à beaucoup utiliser le verbe "*linker*". Personnellement il ne me gêne pas du tout en tant que néologisme, sa graphie très anglaise ne laissant aucun doute sur sa prononciation.

- Qu'en est-il de l'usage de ce mot sur ce site ? Est-ce que c'est correct de répondre à une question sur le français en utilisant des gros anglicismes ?

Je l'utilise beaucoup personnellement, quand je parle à des gens qui savent ce que ça veut dire, mais je ne sais pas si c'est une bonne idée de l'utiliser ici.

- Comment s'en passer ? Comment formuler autrement le fait de donner un lien ?

Je me suis retrouvé à vouloir écrire la phrase :

> Pour résumer l'article linké par Untel, ...

Et je ne voyais vraiment pas d'autre façon de la tourner (l'utilisateur avait répondu à une question par un commentaire en donnant le lien d'un article).

Comment: Pourquoi pas *partagé* ? Ce dernier a gagné beaucoup de sens pour un lien, notamment au niveau du "partage" sur les réseaux sociaux.

Comment: Moi je contourne le pb en écrivant *proposé en lien par*. Maintenant, découvrant la suggestion de @Carnelune, je la trouve pas mal et adhère. Pour ce qui est du droit aux anglicismes, c'est sur le méta qu'il faut poser cette question.

Comment: FWIW, La réponse ["lié ici"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21624/et-pour-ce-la-nommames-lisle-%C3%A8s-coudres-sens-et-choix-de-pr%C3%A9position/26922#26922) et puis celle [ici](https://stackoverrun.com/fr/q/3204747#14522766) évitent l'anglicisme en employant *lié* avec *par* et *dans* respectivement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Savoir si utiliser de gros anglicisme sur ce site est approprié est en effet probablement une question plus adapté au méta *(meta)*, mais puisqu’elle est posée ici, tentons quand même d’y répondre.

J’ai vu d’un peu tout sur le site :

- Un belge a réédité sa réponse après qu’on lui eut indiqué qu’un terme qu’il avait utilisé était un belgicisme. Il désire éviter ce genre de régionalisme sur ce site en particulier, et ne s’était pas rendu compte de la nature du mot qu’il incluait dans sa réponse.
- Un québécois (bibi, en l’occurrence), qui à quelques reprises déjà s’est fait le relai de québécismes mal compris ou relevés tels par certains. S’il y a incompréhension, il ajuste en mettant de l’avant le terme plus générique, mais en y joignant le terme originalement choisi, parce qu’il aime découvrir des régionalismes et se dit qu’il n’est peut-être pas seul dans son cas.
- Des questions à propos de termes d’origine clairement anglaise, pour savoir leur degré de pénétration dans la langue familière ou davantage si affinités :

  - Sur [*yes*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32163/13100)
  - Sur *email/mail* : [en 2012](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2467/13100), [de nouveau en 2018](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32179/13100)
  - Sur les nombres d’ordre indéterminé mais très grands : [*gazillions*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/28974/13100), [*zillions*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32175/13100)
  - À propos des [*potatoes*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/22415/13100)
- Des réponses à tendance très puriste ([*Peut-on dire « une auteure »*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31922/13100)), d’autres plus progressistes ([Sûrement ou surement ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7229/13100))

Que faire alors ? On pourra opter pour différentes approches.

Si la question est très pointue et faite par quelqu’un maîtrisant bien le français, peut-être ne sera-t-elle pas visitée par ceux qui commencent à apprendre le français. Commettre un anglicisme là ne risque probablement pas d’induire en erreur qui que ce soit sur ce qui est acceptable ou non dans les différents niveaux de langues utilisés.

Ailleurs, en général, on peut utiliser l’anglicisme en demandant le terme approprié, si celui-ci nous échappe sur le moment. Ou on peut le mettre entre guillemets, ce qui pourra être perçu comme l’utilisation reconnue d’un pis-aller, si le terme français équivalent soit trop rarement utilisé, s’il ne traduit pas exactement la notion désirée ou s’il est d’une manière ou d’une autre considéré comme dépassé ou pas assez à la mode; ou il pourrait aussi être perçu par d’autres comme une requête à le remplacer si l’on pense au mot qui fera.

Quant au fait de proposer un hyperlien, comme l’a déjà fait remarquer [Papa Poule](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/6011) en commentaire sous la question, Je, Montée de lait, utilise simplement [***lier***](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26922/13100), qui me semble assez clair. Je me dis que si je peux lier avec une corde, qui peut aussi être désignée comme un lien, je pourrais tout aussi bien lier avec un hyperlien, qui n’est lui aussi qu’un type particulier de lien.

On pourrait aussi utiliser ***mettre en lien un article*** ou ***mis en lien par Untel dans sa réponse***.

Je ne crois pas néanmoins que ***linker*** porte à confusion, et le terme est assez communément utilisé, à l’oral comme à l’écrit (du moins dans un certain registre d’écriture, un peu détendu) pour qu’on n’y voit pas là un anglicisme qui portât qui que ce soit au bûcher.

Bien entendu, le français parlé et le français écrit sont deux langues que bien des vides séparent. Si l’anglicisme écrit est traqué et annihilé au Québec lorsqu’un mot ou une tournure, si rare et poussiéreuse soit-elle, permet de l’éviter, l’anglicisme fleurit abondamment dans la langue orale (refuser de le reconnaître est vain...). L’Europe francophone semble accepter davantage ses anglicismes. Bien que ceux-ci soient moins nombreux qu’au Québec, ils sont peut-être plus représentés à l’écrit.

Comment: Même en Europe francophone, je perçois souvent des différences concernant les anglicismes entre la France et la Belgique, où les anglicismes me semblent plus tolérés, et on rencontre même des "belgo-anglicismes", comme *ce concert est sold-out*.

Comment: @Greg Effectivement,l'explication étant surement à chercher du côté du multilinguisme belge et de l'emploi assez fréquent de l'anglais comme langue de compromis dans le monde du travail ou ailleurs. Accessoirement je pense être le belge dont il est question dans la réponse, et effectivement je préfère éviter les belgicismes pour peu que j'en sois conscient car ceux qui viennent ici dans le but d'apprendre pourraient rencontrer des difficultés avec ceux-ci... et tant qu'à être sur un forum de puristes, essayons de les respecter :-)

Comment: @Greg Je ne suis guère qualifié pour remettre votre parole en doutes, et ne vois pas non plus en votre affirmation qqch de surprenant. Je discutais simplement de l'usage que les gens en font: quand je lis des textes d'Europe, même de gens très respectables, j'y vois des anglicismes qui seraient à coup sûr marqués d'infâmie au Québec. Les Québécois ne se gênent pourtant pas pour en utiliser, bien plus que les Européens que je connais ici, mais ils restent principalement dans la sphère plus evanescente de l'oral.

Comment: @LaurentS. Vous êtes effectivement le Belge en question. Je ne voulais pas vous nommer sans votre accord, et suis donc demeuré vague. Je me rappelle une correction que vous avez faites de *farde*, et le commentaire l'accompagnant.

Answer (score 4):

Je ne parcours ce site que depuis assez peu de temps, et je ne peux donc répondre à ta première question sur les habitudes tacites en matière d'anglicismes. Personnellement, je préfère les éviter au maximum et diversifier mon vocabulaire. Avec un peu de chance, j'apprendrai ainsi un nouveau mot à quelqu'un !

Quant à ta seconde question : la mise en place des liens hypertextes est assez récente, ou tout du moins sa démocratisation. Le vocable associé n'est donc pas clairement établi. Toutefois, avec l'émergence des réseaux sociaux il est de plus en plus fréquent d'utiliser le terme *partager*. Tellement fréquent d'ailleurs qu'il m'arrive de l'utiliser sans préciser qu'il s'agit d'un lien.

> Je t'ai partagé un article très intéressant !

Answer (score 1):

Selon le contexte et la technique utilisée pour donner le lien, on pourrait dire:

> Selon l'article mis en lien par Untel
>
> Selon l'article (re)posté par Untel
>
> Selon l'article référencé par Untel
>
> Selon l'article partagé par Untel

Je découvre aussi le verbe *hyperlier* mais les rares références à ce sujet n'indiquent pas si le verbe peut être transitif. On pourrait alors dire:

> Selon l'article hyperlié par Untel